# How to Union the title in sql query with data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

I want the title for the SQL query.How Can I generate it? In the following code `ContractID` is `int`, `Contract Number` is `nvarchar` and `ClientContractNumber` is `nvarchar`.

I have tried the following Code

```
SELECT * 
INTO #temp 
FROM 
    (SELECT ContractID,ContractNumber, ClientContractNumber 
     FROM dbo.bsContract 
     WHERE ContractNumber = 'CR6359-V1') t

SELECT 'Title',' ','  '
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'ContractID', 'ContractNumber', 'ClientContractNumber'
UNION ALL 
SELECT * 
FROM #temp

DROP TABLE #temp
```

The following error occurs:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Title' to data type int.

The expected output SHOULD BE:

```
Title 

ContactID     ContractNumber    ClientContractNumber 
----------------------------------------------------    
6368           cr1234              newContract
```

Comment: You might want to actually handle this in your presentation layer, rather than directly in the database.

Comment: Yes but this data I have to Export into excel directly from stored procedure.I don't need to show this data on html page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use cast for ContractID

```
SELECT 'Title',' ','  '

UNION ALL 

SELECT 'ContractID','ContractNumber','ClientContractNumber'
UNION ALL 
SELECT cast( ContractID as varchar(50)),ContractNumber, FROM #temp
DROP TABLE #temp
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the contract ID to varchar before unioning since union requires all the datatypes to match.
Edit:

```
SELECT * INTO #temp FROM (SELECT cast(ContractID as varchar) ContractID,ContractNumber,ClientContractNumber 
FROM dbo.bsContract WHERE ContractNumber='CR6359-V1') t



SELECT 'Title' ContractID,' ' ContractNumber,'  ' ContractNumber

UNION ALL 

SELECT 'ContractID' ContractID,'ContractNumber' ContractNumber,'ClientContractNumber' ContractNumber
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM #temp
DROP TABLE #temp
```

Comment: this is the error i got 
Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 6
No column name was specified for column 1 of 't'.
Msg 1038, Level 15, State 5, Line 1
An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name.